# Can't launch ASP files with the IIS localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis

I set up everything from modules, CGI's, and IIS_IUSRS read permission for web config file. But when I launch the ASP files, it redirects me to the store to find apps that would open the server, in which the browser should be doing.

P.S. We don't have network at home, but determined to learn :)

Comment: What exactly are you learning? Classic ASP or ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? They are completely different things, so need different setup. Also you need to reveal more on how you set up IIS. If you find it hard to describe, show screen shots.

Answer (score 1):

How did you access the asp file? IIS shouldn't prompt for determine app. It sounds just like you are trying to access the file by double click .asp file.
If you want to access the file from IIS. Please put it to the root folder of your website and then access it via your domain name or localhost.

To support IIS, you only need to enable ASP and common http feature from turn windows features on or off.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis